# Python - local variable referenced before assignment for variable that should shadow one outside of scope

Tags: python, scope, shadowing

This code does not work (`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment`):

```
x = 5
def thing():
    x = x + 1
thing()
```

This one does (only changed `x` to `i`):

```
x = 5
def thing():
    i = x + 1
thing()
```

I expected that with the first one, it would create a new variable called `x` with a value of 6 (leaving the outside variable unchanged), which is what `i` is in the second example. What's going on here?
It seems that when a variable is created for the first time in the scope, it checks to see if it exists in any outer scope and raises an error if it has already been found and raises an error if it has already been found.

Now, my question is, what is the purpose of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python doesn't let you use the same symbol to refer to two different variables. Either `x` is `global`, in which case you have to declare `global x` at the beginning of the function (and then both occurrences of `x` refer to the global inside the function); or it is not, in which case the `x` you refer to in `x + 1` is not yet defined.

In a weird way your reasoning makes sense, at least in this small toy example, but it should be easy to see how the semantics you assume would be catastrophically hard to understand for a human in any larger block of code with many variables.

Comment: Also has some interesting implications: if `x = []` and defined outside, `x.append(0)` works while `x += [0]` is not allowed inside.